# Problems with the format json using java

Tags: java, json

Hello everyone i have problem with json format,when set all variables of my class then the Object json become like this:

```
{"patientid":1,"category":"Dskolia","game":"meleti2","level":"eikones"}
```

but the correct format of json is:

```
{"patientid:"1","category":"Dskolia","game":"meleti2","level":"eikones"}
```

could anyone give some idea!

Comment: Your "correct" one looks malformed to me, and the one you're actually getting looks correct.

Comment: indeed, json is totaly ok with `"patientid": 1` since it will be interpreted as integer, which it ofcourse is. if you have something in "" in json, it will be interpreted as string - which you don't want for an id.

Comment: are you sure?Because when i try to post the specific json object to my server  the system crash out....this my code from the server side below look at : i have problem at line  pst.setInt(2, entity.getPatientid().getPid());

Comment: @Gewure if the patientid is type of other class,  in this case is the same? the format of json? mean if ideclare instead public int patientid into public Patient patientid;  Patient is another class where has onle one variable int pid;

Comment: Even if your ID is a string the second one would still be wrong for a json format you miss one double quote. The correct way is either `{"patientid":"1", ...` or `{"patientid":1, ...`

Comment: If Patientid is an object it is still wrong it should be something like `{"patientid":{ "pid":1 }, ...`

Answer (score 0):

The first JSON appears to be correct, because numerical values don't have quotes around them.  If you want patientid to have quotes around it, you should declare it as String instead of int.  I would also recommend using Integer instead of int.